# Embedded tomcat returning blank pages

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm running a maven web application on an embedded tomcat, but when I try to access it via browser, all I get is a blank page with no content at all. Perhaps there may be a problem when the application is starting. I could find out more from the logs but I cannot find them anywhere. What could be the cause of my problem and how to configure the embedded Tomcat to write logs somewhere? This is how I start the embedded Tomcat:

```
tomcat = new Tomcat();
tomcat.setPort(0);
tomcat.addWebapp("/", new File("src/main/webapp/").getAbsolutePath());
tomcat.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to configure properly the logging framework used by tomcat,which I believe is Java Util Logging.

I'm not familiar with it so can't really help with the details, but it may be possible to use another logging framework.